# update a column with row_num series from a date reference table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table my_table with 3 columns, 1st col is dates and 2nd is period and 3rd is dayofweek.  1st column shows the dates ( currently, the last date is June 28, 2020), 2nd column shows the periodid (currently, the last period id is 202012 ) and the 3rd column is the dayofWeek ( Sunday ).  Every financial year ends on the last Sunday of June which, in above data it is June 28,2019. It will then be followed by the next financial year that will start in June 29,2020. Since periodid represents the 12 months of the financial year, the periodid for June 29,2020 will be 2021 plus 01( period 1) combined together making it 202101. I dont have data yet for 2021 period. What I have is the complete dates for the next financial year which is from June 29,2020 to June 27,2021.

- period always ends on the last sunday of a month and starts on monday after that.
- 12 periods must be present. 202101 ... 202112

I tried generating series but it's too complex for me. I cant get the results

Result shown below

```
  Dates       Period    Dayofweek
2020-06-28    202012    Sunday
2020-06-29    202101    Monday
    .
    .
    .
2021-06-27    202112    Sunday
2021-06-28    202201    Monday
```

Comment: I didn't understand what is a period and what the new column should contain.

Comment: i hope i made it clear

Comment: what happens at the year between June 28,2019 and June 29,2020? What are you expecting? Generating the Period column?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the actual question is.  Are you trying to calculate the period based on the date?

Comment: @S-Man yes, I would like to generate the period column.

Comment: @Jeremy yes. I only have the Dates column

Answer (score 0):

You haven't been able to create a simple generate_series for this because it simply will not work. While the following solution is bases on a series considerable manipulation is required. Two issues involved:

1. Last Sunday of month: This is not a fixed interval. Ie given the last Sun of any month an interval of 1 month does not produce the last sum of the next month.
2. Generation of Period: This changes at the beginning, the end, and even in the middle of the sequence; and is different depending on what DOW as it forms the boundary of the period and it's necessary to the side of the boundary being processed.

The below solves each of these issued. For the Last Sunday of the month I've provided 2 utility functions I've used for quite some time. The Period issue resolved in the case predicates in the queries. The overall solution the is wrapped in a SQL function generating the result. That function requires only the fiscal year desired as an integer (ie 2021).

```
create or replace function utl_date_next_dow(
    dow_in text,
    date_in date)
  returns date 
  language plpgsql immutable strict security definer
as $$
-- Given a DOW and a Date return the next calendar date for the specified dow.
declare
    l_days     text[] = array['mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat','sun'];

    l_from_nbr integer;
    l_dow_nbr  integer;

begin
    l_from_nbr  = extract('isodow' from date_in);  
    l_dow_nbr   = array_position(l_days, lower(substring(dow_in,1,3)));

    if l_dow_nbr <= l_from_nbr
    then
        l_dow_nbr = l_dow_nbr+7;
    end if;

    return (date_in +  (l_dow_nbr-l_from_nbr) * '1 days'::interval)::date;
end ;
$$;


create or replace function utl_date_last_dow_in_month(
    dow_in text,
    date_in date)    
  returns date 
  language sql immutable strict security definer
 as $$
-- Given a DOW and a Date return the last calendar date of the specified dow in the month the specified date falls.
select utl_date_next_dow(dow_in,  (date_trunc('month', date_in) + interval '1 month' - interval '8 day')::date);
$$;
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
create or replace function build_fiscal_year_calendar(fiscal_year_in integer)
returns table("Dates" date, "Period" text,  "Day of Week" text)
language sql immutable strict security definer
as $$
with bfyc as (select fiscal_year_in-1::integer fiscal_year, utl_date_last_dow_in_month('sun', make_date(fiscal_year_in-1,06,01)) fy )
select fyd "Dates",  period::text "Period", trim(to_char(fyd, 'Day')) "Day of Week" 
  from (
        select fiscal_year
             , fy
             , utl_date_last_dow_in_month('sun' ,(fy+nm*interval '1 month')::date) fyd 
             , nm  
             , case when nm = 0 then fiscal_year*100 + 12
                    when nm = 13 then null  
                    else fiscal_year*100 + 100 + nm
               end as period
          from bfyc
             , generate_series ( 0, 12) nm 
        UNION ALL       
        select fiscal_year
             , fy
             , (utl_date_last_dow_in_month('sun' ,(fy+nm*interval '1 month')::date)+interval '1 day')::date fyd 
             , nm  
             , case when nm = 12 then fiscal_year*100 + 201
                    when nm = 13 then null
                    else fiscal_year*100 + 100 + nm + 1
               end as period
          from bfyc
             , generate_series ( 0, 12) nm ) x
 where period is not null
 order by fyd ;
$$; 



---- test: generate the fiscal year calendar for FY2021 (June 2020-June 2021)
select * from build_fiscal_year_calendar(2021);
```

NOTE: In the above the term DOW stands for the Day of Week Name (ie Sunday, Monday, ...) instead of the Postgres use of dow as the day number within the week. ("isodow" being the exception to day name usage).

Comment: wooooh I will check this out. Thank you